# LAN to LAN Connectivity of Moxa routers

Tags: routing, router, network, lan

I am with background of DevOps and to optimize stuff in office i am assigned a networking task with not much experience of networking.

My scenario is like below

I have two moxa (EDR-810) routers with following LAN Configurations

Moxa 1:
10.17.0.1/28

Moxa 2:
10.17.0.17/28

So each have almost 14 IPs, Now i want to connect each other so device on Moxa1 can ping to devices on Moxa 2.

Please guide me how i can achieve it?
1- Use Network Cable(RJ45) or Fiber Cable? These Moxas has G1 and G2 ports too.
2- Do i have to add some routes/rules?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not Moxa-specific but generally:

1. connect the routers any which way so that they share an IP subnet - via direct link, tunnnel, ...
2. make sure each router knows the subnet(s) behind the other router by setting up either static routes or a routing protocol in between (OSPF, RIP, ...)
3. if a router is working as a firewall you might need rules to permit traffic each way
4. direct your clients to use their local router as gateway, either as default gateway (possibly via DHCP) or with a static or dynamic route